# Hibernate - Find object by double value in column

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to get a `Processor` object from the database by value. I have a Processor table in database where the schema is id, value and type_id. I have `ProcessorService` as a DAO.

```
Processor processor = processorService.findByValue(Double.valueOf(cpu));
```

The database has existing processor objects. Where processor is NULL. I think there is a problem with comparing the double value. Because this works for the other class of objects.

[image]

This is `findByValue()` method

```
public Processor findByValue(Double value) {
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("value", value));
    return (Processor) criteria.uniqueResult();
}

protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
    return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
}
```

[Edit]

I am getting When I call `findByValue()`.

```
type mismatch can't assign object value to primitive
```

Processor class

```
public class Processor {
    public static final int serialId = 104;

    private int id;
    private Double value;
    private Type typeId;
    private Collection<Smartphone> processorId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "value", precision = 4, scale = 2, columnDefinition="DECIMAL(4,2)")
    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I call findByValue and I get null but object exists.

Comment: you should add it in your question then

Comment: And of course createEntityCriteria

Comment: I got type mismatch can't assign object value to primitive

Comment: Is it `DOUBLE`?  Or is it `DECIMAL(4,2)`?  "1.84" in each of those is not equal to the other.

Comment: It is `Double`. But I removed it and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("value", value.doubleValue()));`